# What is the top speed of swimmers when they leave the blocks?

Tags: swimming

At the beginning of a race, swimmers dive off the starting blocks into the water. I would like to know how fast they are moving when they enter the air, before they hit the water.

Thus far my search attempts have resulted only in discussions of response time, training to increase this speed, or speed of the athletes as they move through the water.

I am looking for a concrete empirical measurement of their horizontal movement, such as in meters per second.

Answer (score -3):

I just tried roughly calculating it with a video of a championship and I estimate the speed at 3 m/s but the video is a bit shaky.

Comment: Evidence would need to be a bit more scientific than that, I'm afraid.